# How to invoke hooks in different components based on RESTful fetch call?

Tags: reactjs, rest, promise, react-hooks, fetch

Assume a RESTful `fetch` call for some configuration info is made in the `App.js` file; immediately when an App loads.

How can hooks be triggered in various components to set state based on the results of said fetch?

For example, imagine a fetch that returns this object:

```
{
    "name": "Xi JinPing",
    "email": "xi.jinping@example.com"
}
```

When it returns, how can setState hooks be called in different components?

```
 fetch("http://www.example.com:8888/config")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(conf => {
         // HERE... we have our config 
         // how to set various app states with hook calls?
         // Such as:
         //   In <Name /> component: setName(conf.name)
         //   In <Email /> component: setEmail(conf.email)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the states in the parent component, and pass them down as props:

```
const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://www.example.com:8888/config")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(conf => {
        setName(conf.name);
        setEmail(conf.email);
     });
  }, []);
  return (<>
    <Name {...{ name }} />
    <Email {...{ email }} />
  </>);
};
```

```
const Name = ({ name }) => {
  return <span>{name}</span>;
}
// etc
```